Fantasy manga where the main character is a kid and doesn't trust anyone
I read this maybe 5 years ago. It's about a kid main character (around 10 years old) who doesn't trust anyone. I think his mom dies/is killed and a slightly older adventurer girl tries to take care of him. He does not trust her initially bit he warms up to her eventually. He also becomes an adventurer and carries knives (I think).

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! Could you [edit] your question to expand on any science-fictional or fantastical happenings in this manga? Was there magic? Ghosts? Goblins?

I’m voting to close this question because as described this does not appear to be about science-fiction or fantasy

The term 'adventurer' in manga typically refers to people who raid dungeons and kill monsters. That said, @user174854, it would be helpful if you could edit this question to be more specific about any fantasy elements in this story.

is it Otome Game no Heroine de Saikyou Survival ? but mc is female...
